# NGINX not recognizing $request

Tags: nginx, web-server, http, regex

Well.. NGINX or me guess.. something that I'm not doing OK.

The point is, I'm getting some request from bots of this type:

```
91.123.1.56 - - [04/Apr/2016:12:13:39 +0200] "V\x5CxA1po\x5CxA9^\x5Cx8F\x5Cx90B\x5CxE1\x5CxDE\x5CxAC\x5CxE7\x5CxEE\x5Cx1DW\x5Cx1A\x5CxAC\x5CxA8L\x5Cx10\x5CxE4\x5CxCB\x5Cx84\x5CxEC\x5CxB2\x5CxE7\x5Cx90G\x5CxF35\x5CxC4+\x5CxD8\x5CxD8\x5Cx19\x5CxE8\x5Cx7F`\x5CxCF\x5CxE6\x5Cx075\x5Cx01kE\x5CxB7\x5CxAE{\x5CxC4\x5Cx0B\x5Cx82\x5CxB8*\x5CxA2\x5Cx03\x5CxFC\x5Cx89\x5CxA4\x5CxD99A\x5Cx80s" 400 166 "-" "-" "-"
```

The point is, I want nginx to respond with 444 rather than 400, if it's possible.

So, for trying it first, I wrote a new line under the main server block (block which setups what happens when server is called via IP)

```
    server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    # include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    if ($request ~* testrequest) {
        return 444;
    }

    location / {
        return 444;
    }

    location /status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log off;
        allow 192.168.1.0/24;
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

The line:

```
if ($request ~* testrequest) {
        return 444;
    }
```

Had in first place a regexp for catching the xYZ characters, but since I saw it didn't work, I decided to try something simpler (testrequest)

And, if I make a telnet connection to the server (using IP, not any server name) and make the "testrequest" HTTP request, I'm still getting a 400 HTTP response.

I used the $request variable since it contains the raw request.

I also tried putting the IF block inside the location / but it didn't work, besides, I also find it a bit pointless.

I'd thank a lot any help in here. I know a 400 response is not to be worried about, but I really prefer to close the connection if the request is something nasty-bot like.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't you be better matching the user-agent, rather than relying on the request being an exact match?

Comment: No user agent is given in the request, besides, is usually common to see normal user agents (Chrome, Opera,...) being passed in these type of things. And, I'm trying an exact match just to make it work. Like I said, I'm gonnna use a regexp to match a request of type x##\ and several more.